# Overflow Error in Access form linked to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have recently migrated data from an Access back-end to SQL Server.  There are 6 to 7 users entering data to the new tables via an Access front-end application.  There are two specific sub-forms within the main form that are causing an overflow error, and I suspect it is either the date fields or numeric fields causing the issue as these are the only sub-forms containing either of these data types other than one date on the parent form.

We have a data warehouse that houses all of the data that comes from the loan origination system that our company uses.  The data warehouse has fields that correspond to the data that is being updated in SQL Server, and I set the data types up to match the corresponding fields.  The fields and the type of information being entered are as follows:

- Field 1: `datetime`, date only
- Field 2: `datetime`, date only
- Field 3: `numeric(23, 10)`, interest rate - number with a decimal and two places
- Field 4: `numeric(23, 10)`, numeric value between 0 and 20,000,000
- Field 5: `numeric(23, 10)`, numeric value between 0 and 200,000
- Field 6: `numeric(23, 10)`, numeric value between 0 and 200,000

I haven't seen evidence that anyone is inputting invalid values, and when I have tried to in testing it doesn't create the overflow error.  There are no calculations included in these fields - users are directly inputting data.  I did not make any adjustments to the number formats in the form so they number format is blank and the decimal places are automatic.  The issue doesn't happen on all records, but it consistently happens at varying points of the user updating the forms with the fields in question.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you open the linked table in Access in Design view, what data types does Access show for these fields?

Comment: mind including the test values you used and what criteria you are using to qualify that values should result in an overflow. even better, would be including your unit tests, if you have them.

Comment: The two dates both show as Date/Time data types, and the four numeric fields show as Number data types with the field size listed as Decimal.  Users won't ever be entering more than two decimal places for any of the numeric fields.

Comment: Are you validating the data typed in to make sure dates are valid and numbers don't have things like `$` and `,` in them?